# How to introduce typescript on a big nodeJS code basis step by step?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I do own quite a big code basis implemented in JavaScript based on NodeJS. I do want to give typescript a try and want to implement all new modules in typescript. Just to see how it performs and how I like the idea. I do need to be able to revert back at any time so I do not want to put to much effort into the migration.

I started by using WebStorm and Gulp to support typescript. I created a new module and used the import / require combination.

```
import settings = require("./settings");
import _ = require("lodash-node");
```

By doing so I receive a couple of errors.

```
Error:(22, 27) TS2307: Cannot find external module './settings'.
Error:(23, 20) TS2307: Cannot find external module 'lodash-node'.
```

Those modules have no typescript definition file and are plain javascript modules (lodash is obviously a external library). I do have a couple of dependencies and I do not want to create definitions manually even if they are just empty stubs. As mentioned I do want to keep the integration as simple as possible.

Is there a general flag or something like that I can set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to proceed (if you don't want type information for a module) is to write:

```
declare module "lodash-node" {
  var notTyped: any; // naming is unimportant here
  export = notTyped;
}
```

Put that in a separate .d.ts file and `/// <reference>` it. Then `_` will be of type `any` in your implementation file and the compiler won't complain about not know what module you're talking about.

Comment: Ok I get this, but that means I need to create such a typescript definition file for each single nodeJS module I have created so for as soon as I want to use it, right?

Comment: I have troubles achieving this, I did exactly what you recommended but it still fails. I created a new file `lodash-node.d.ts` in a folder called `lib`. It contains the module declaration. In my typescript module I use `/// <reference path="../lib/lodash-node.d.ts"/>` to reference it and `import _ = require("lodash-node");` to include it. It still gives me the error listed above. Only when I put that `lodas-node.d.ts` into the root directory it works. But this is not intended.

Answer (score 0):

You can use webpack's [typescript-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-loader) and start from there. Make sure you put `target: 'node'` on your webpack config so you don't have all the browser junk.